# How to use javascript to identify a customer with no signon

Tags: javascript, cookies, ip

We have a piece of javascript for which we would would like to use separate processing logic if there is a particular customer. However, it's a public site, and the customer isn't required to log in.

Is there any way to identify the customer initially without requiring a loging? I guess ip address is a possibility, but that seems undependable.

Comment: Well how do you know what people you want to treat specially? What makes them different from other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie) are commonly used for this.

If you only need to access this data client-side, consider using [localstorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage).

Remember that with either method, you're only identifying a browser that has been to your site before.  Anyone can use that computer, and you wouldn't know it was a new user.  It's also important to be careful with those tokens so that someone else has a hard time impersonating that user.  Rotating a session ID regularly is a good idea, so that if someone does get your session ID it has a limited shelf life for re-use.

Do not use IP addresses, as there are entire buildings that can share a single public IP address thanks to NAT.